# delete link is going to show link in rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

```
<% for available_times in @available_times %>

      <td><%= link_to "Show", available_times %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_available_times_path(available_times) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Destroy", available_times, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :available_times
```

javascripts included

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>  
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1306892842" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/jquery-ui.js?1305678932" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: What is the issue here, the delete link is supposed to be shown.

Comment: I dont see that you included jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the include of `rails.js`. That file either implements the Prototype or Jquery behaviour you need. Since you are using jquery-ui (not jquery?), the best way to install all the jquery file, is using the jquery-rails gem, and running the generator:

```
rails g jquery:install
```

and then include the `rails.js` file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For non-GET requests like this, you'll want to install [jquery-rails](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs).